# wp_query order by rand is repeating posts

Tags: wp-query, query

So I am trying to select clinents with the following code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">

    <?php                       

    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>3, 'post_type' => 'clients', 'orderby' => 'rand'));

    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {

        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {

            $the_query->the_post();

            $color = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'color', true);

            ?>   

          <div class="cimage">

            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($the_query->ID)): ?>

                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($the_query->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="responsive">

            <?php endif; ?> 

          </div>

    <?php

        }

    }
```

But that is duplicating the clients, how can I stop the above query repeating the same client?

Comment: Duplicating on the same page? Or are the results paginated? You can't do random sorting with pagination because they're randomised differently on every page.

Comment: Is there any way to select 3 random posts from the database?